# Are feature values random variable realizations, or random variables themselves?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, random-variable, iid

I'm new to ML/stats so got confused with what I supposed was simple notation.

For simplicity, say I have a data set with just one column:

[image]

From probabilistic perspective, I had understood that X represents a random variable, and each row value is an observation (i.e. realization) of this random variable. X then has a distribution, which let's assume is Gaussian.

I got confused however when I studied the Maximum Likelihood Estimate (MLE) method. In MLE literature, it's assumed that the individual row values are iid, which then permits us to multiply their distributions:

[image]

Isn't iid however a property of random variables? In other words seems MLE is assuming that each row value by itself is a random variable with its own distribution. Doesn't this contradict the previous interpretation that X is a random variable and the row values are just specific realizations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, $X$ is a RV, and the listed values can be interpreted as its realizations. In MLE, we don't multiply their distributions. We again use $X$'s distribution but substitute our data points in it. $p(x_i|\theta)$ actually means $p_X(x_i|\theta)$, i.e. the value of PDF of $X$ at the specific point $x_i$ (something that represents some sort of probability measure). MLE just tries to maximize your probability of having those realizations.

And right, being iid is a property belonging to RVs although, not related to this discussion directly, technically constants are also RVs (with probability of equaling their value is $1$), and constants are also iid. But, here we're not talking about the iid-ness of constants/realizations. Each realization, $x_i$, is assumed to be drawn from the distribution of $X_i$ that has the same distribution with $X$. Consider the rows as grades of students $i=1,2,3,4$, i.e. $X_i$. Each student's grade can be thought of as a random variable. Having realizations of them doesn't change this.

This confusion arises in many other places, not just MLE; for instance, sample mean. Your sample mean is $(100+200+300+400)/4=250$. But, [sample mean](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Sample_mean_and_covariance) has also a distribution.